# AttributeError: module "__" has no attribute "___"

Tags: python, module

I have been wanting to play around with mouse and keyboard automation and I have just downloaded a package called "mouse"(https://github.com/boppreh/mouse). unfortunately, whenever I try to use any method described by either the documentation or this tutorial(https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/control-mouse-python) I get an error: "AttributeError: module 'mouse' has no attribute...". I have never had this issue with any other module before. Wondering if anyone knows what is causing this and how it might be fixed.

Thanks.

[image]